# AttributeError: type object 'PrecisionRecallDisplay' has no attribute 'from_estimator'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

Here is my import lines:

```
from sklearn.metrics import PrecisionRecallDisplay
```

When I type

```
PrecisionRecallDisplay
```

I get

```
sklearn.metrics._plot.precision_recall_curve.PrecisionRecallDisplay
```

insted of

```
sklearn.metrics.PrecisionRecallDisplay
```

I am trying to run the following code line:

```
display = PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_estimator(lr_clf, x_test, y_test, name = "Logistic Regression")
```

and I get this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'PrecisionRecallDisplay' has no attribute 'from_estimator'
```

I am using the latest version of sklearn.('0.24.2')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

0.24.2 is *not* the latest version of scikit-learn—as of this writing, [version 1.0](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/releases/tag/1.0) was released two days ago. You will need to upgrade to that version to use `PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_estimator` because the the 0.24.2 release predates the [addition of `PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_estimator`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/d4da69082257fd9f162f746ba7c23e5f60f0aa26/sklearn/metrics/_plot/precision_recall_curve.py) by a few months.

If you are using conda, you can upgrade with

```sh
conda upgrade -c conda-forge scikit-learn
```

or, with `pip`,

```sh
python -m pip install scikit-learn --upgrade
```

Comment: I'm on `scikit_learn 1.0.2` and still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been mentioned, an update to version 1.0 at least is needed.

You can either use for conda,

```
conda upgrade -c conda-forge scikit-learn
```

or for pip

```
python -m pip install scikit-learn --upgrade
```

(if it still does not work) MY UPDATE:

I have been struggling for time and deleting previous scikit-learn from my environment and installing again solved the issue:

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
```

then follow the same example above for installation.